# How to remove elements from array of dates between hours ranges Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

My array is generated by the

```
   start_date = (Date.today + 10.hours + 30.minutes).to_datetime       
   end_date = (Date.today + 1.day + 18.hours).to_datetime
   period = 0.5/24 
   array = start_date.step(end_date, period).to_a
```

this is the result (but this result is going to cover max 62 days)

```
array = 
  [Sat, 25 Feb 2023 10:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 11:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 11:30:00 +0000, 
  Sat, 25 Feb 2023 12:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 12:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 13:00:00 +0000,
  Sat, 25 Feb 2023 13:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 14:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 14:30:00 +0000, 
  Sat, 25 Feb 2023 15:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 15:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 16:00:00 +0000, 
  Sat, 25 Feb 2023 16:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 17:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 17:30:00 +0000, 
  Sat, 25 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 18:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 19:00:00 +0000, 
  Sat, 25 Feb 2023 19:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 20:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 20:30:00 +0000, 
  Sat, 25 Feb 2023 21:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 21:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 22:00:00 +0000, 
  Sat, 25 Feb 2023 22:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 23:00:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 23:30:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 00:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 00:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 01:00:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 01:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 02:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 02:30:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 03:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 03:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 04:00:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 04:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 05:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 05:30:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 06:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 06:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 07:00:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 07:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 08:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 08:30:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 09:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 09:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 10:00:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 10:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 11:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 11:30:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 12:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 12:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 13:00:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 13:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 14:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 14:30:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 15:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 15:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 16:00:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 16:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 17:00:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 17:30:00 +0000, 
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000]
```

From this array I want to remove all the datetimes that are between beginning of each day till 10:29 o'clock and after 18:00 o'clock till the end of each the day.

Desired result:

```
array = 
  [Sat, 25 Feb 2023 10:30:00 +0000, Sat, 25 Feb 2023 11:00:00 +0000, ....... Sat, 25 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000,
  Sun, 26 Feb 2023 10:30:00 +0000, Sun, 26 Feb 2023 11:00:00 +0000, ....... Sun, 26 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000]
```

I'ved tried

```
 w_start_time = (start_date + 8.hours + 1.minute).strftime('%k:%M:%S')
 w_end_time = (start_date - 1.minute).strftime('%k:%M:%S')
        
 hours = array_of_datestimes.reject! { |n| n.strftime('%k:%M:%S').between?(w_start_time, w_end_time) }
```

this returns  nil

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
 w_start_time = (start_date - 1.minute).strftime('%k:%M:%S')
 w_end_time = (start_date + 8.hours - 1.minute).strftime('%k:%M:%S')

 hours = array.filter { |n| n.strftime('%k:%M:%S').between?(w_start_time, w_end_time) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways.

**Convert to minutes.**

```
array.accept! { |date| (630..1080).cover?(60*date.hour + date.min) }
```

where `630 = 60*10+30` and `1080 = 60*18`. See [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F), which only uses range end points, making it very efficient.

**Count to determine which elements to keep**

We see that on the first day we wish to keep the first

```
(18.0 - 10.5)/0.5 + 1 = 16
```

elements. As there are 48 30-minute intervals per day, we wish to remove the next

```
48 - 16 = 32
```

elements. We therefore may create an enumerator that generates `false` 16 times, then `true` 32 times, then repeats, where an element of `array` is to be removed if the corresponding value of the enumerator equals `true`. We can use [Array#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle) to create this enumerator.

```
reject = ([false]*16 + [true]*32).cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
  #     false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
  #     true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
  #     true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
  #     true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
  #     true, true]:cycle>
```

We then simply write

```
array.reject! { reject.next }
```

---

To illustrate this calculation suppose `array` held an array of strings corresponding to the `DateTime` elements of the given array.

```
array = [
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 10:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 11:00:00 +0000", 
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 11:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 12:00:00 +0000", 
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 12:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 13:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 13:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 14:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 14:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 15:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 15:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 16:00:00 +0000", 
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 16:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 17:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 17:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 18:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 19:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 19:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 20:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 20:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 21:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 21:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 22:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 22:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 23:00:00 +0000",
  "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 23:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 00:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 00:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 01:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 01:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 02:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 02:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 03:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 03:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 04:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 04:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 05:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 05:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 06:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 06:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 07:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 07:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 08:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 08:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 09:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 09:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 10:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 10:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 11:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 11:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 12:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 12:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 13:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 13:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 14:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 14:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 15:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 15:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 16:00:00 +0000", 
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 16:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 17:00:00 +0000",
  "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 17:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000"
]
```

Then

```
array.reject! { reject.next }
  #=> ["Sat, 25 Feb 2023 10:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 11:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 11:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 12:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 12:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 13:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 13:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 14:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 14:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 15:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 15:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 16:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 16:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 17:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 17:30:00 +0000", "Sat, 25 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 10:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 11:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 11:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 12:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 12:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 13:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 13:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 14:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 14:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 15:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 15:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 16:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 16:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 17:00:00 +0000",
  #    "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 17:30:00 +0000", "Sun, 26 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000"]
```

---

This clearly works for any number of days provided the first element of the array corresponds to `10:30` on the first day. The time associated with the last element of the array is not required to be `18:00`.

This calculation will be relatively fast as it does require that each `DateTime` element be broken down into hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this :

```
array = array.reject { |date| 
  (date.hour < 10 || (date.hour == 10 && date.min < 30)) || 
  (date.hour >= 18) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you this almost works, the problem is that is removing also  `Sat, 25 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000` and `Sun, 26 Feb 2023 18:00:00 +0000` that i want to keep